# Send asynchronous HTTP requests one after another

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, aiohttp

I am trying to use `aiohttp` to send requests one after another like this

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime


async def main():
    request_url = "https://..."
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            print(datetime.now())
            async with session.get(request_url) as response:
                json_data = await response.json()
            print(json_data)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

So I would expect each datetime print to be 0.2s apart. However, they seem to be about 0.35s apart as I think it takes 0.15s to get the data from the response. Why is this happening? I want it to be asynchronous so it should just go onto the next one?

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you want to use threading, here's an article. https://www.shanelynn.ie/using-python-threading-for-multiple-results-queue/

Comment: @kpie I don't understand why I should need to? Is what I have described as my desired output not the typical functionality of an asynchronous program?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `await` all next code will wait for end of this code.
If you want to run asyncio code asynchronously, you should use functions like `asyncio.gather`

---

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import datetime


async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            print('#', response.status)


async def worker(queue):
    print('START WORKER')
    while True:
        url = await queue.get()
        await fetch(url)
        queue.task_done()


async def control(queue):
    while True:
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        queue.put_nowait('https://docs.python.org/')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(
        control(queue),
        asyncio.gather(*[worker(queue) for _ in range(10)])
    )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Can you explain how I would implement that here please?

Comment: You can't implement it in this way.
If i right understand you code, you want run each request after 0.2 seconds after previous, but ignore time of execution request.

In this case you need create pool of async workers and add control function with timer. In each timer iteration you should add task for http request.

I will update answer with example code.

Answer (score 1):

Sending http request and fetching response back takes some time. You need excluding this time from `asyncio.sleep()` call:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
from datetime import datetime


async def main():
    request_url = "https://..."
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            print(datetime.now())
            t0 = time.monotonic()
            async with session.get(request_url) as response:
                json_data = await response.json()
            print(json_data)
            t1 = time.monotonic()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2 - (t1 - t0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I want to send a request every 0.1s and it takes 0.15s to send a request. The maths doesn't quite add up.

Comment: So what do you want to do? Ask the server faster than it can respond?